# Code/module to evaluate a Boolean expression to be used in awk or bash on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, awk, boolean-expression

I am working on some bash with awk scripts to search many files and return various combinations of lines which match various combinations of conditions.

I would like some way to add the capability for my scripts to be able to handle simple but general Boolean "query" expressions - things like:

```
A AND (B OR C) AND NOT D
```

where A, B, C, and D would be bash or awk variables with values like `TRUE=0` and `FALSE!=0` or the other way around.

My code would set each of the variables and then pass a Boolean expression using these variables to something which could evaluate it.

I don't really need anything very fancy like nested parentheses, but one level would really help. I don't need extensive expression error checking/recovery. If I write a bad expression, it's my problem as long as it doesn't totally kill the rest of my script with something like a bash/awk syntax error.

The solution could be native to bash or awk or an external program called from within either language that returns true or false (0/1).

I know how to hard code such things with if statements, etc., but I need to be able to change conditions for every search, so it can't be hard-coded.

I definitely don't know enough to roll my own parser with something like lex/yacc.

Tools like `sed`, `find`, and `grep` are great, but (at least by themselves), they won't do what I want and are too picky about syntax to use for writing ad hoc queries.

As one alternative, I'm thinking about trying to convert my queries to simple math and putting them through `(( query ))` in bash - e.g. for the example above (without using fully defended syntax to make the example ugly and with all variables being set to 1 for true and 0 for false.)

```
(( $A * ($B + $C) * (! $D) ))
```

Comment: @Skynet - Thanks for the almost instant response. I didn't see that when I was looking through the similar questions before I posted this question, But ... It doesn't tell me how to get from a somewhat more user friendly form to one of the forms bash can successfully process. This will be a frequently used utility which I would like to be a little easier to use than entering a syntactically correct bash expression every time I use it

Comment: `awk 'A&&(B||C)&&!D{Do something}'` ?

Comment: Hmmm. I think this is not a duplicate. At least not duplicate of the mentioned Q...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not exactly got what is your goal, but I created a small [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script to get any boolean expression and write its truth-table. Maybe this helps. It process any braces, AND, OR and NOT expressions. Variable is anything which starts with a letter (on the language you set). The only thing has to be changed is the `COND` variable. It can be set from the command line as well. It works only if your [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) supports associate arrays (`declare -A`).

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

COND="A AND (B OR C) AND NOT DD"

# Convert to bash syntax
cond=${COND// AND / && }
cond=${cond// OR / || }
cond=${cond// NOT / ! }
cond=${cond//^NOT /! }
cond=${cond//(/ ( }
cond=${cond//)/ ) }
# Now $cond can be used in eval adding "((..))" around it.
# The rest of the script prints the complete truth-table

# Collect unique variables
declare -A hvars
for var in $cond; do
  [[ $var =~ ^[[:alpha:]] ]] && hvars[$var]=1
done
# Make vars array
vars=(${!hvars[@]})
# Number of variables
n=${#vars[@]}
# Number or rows in truth-table
((N=1<<n))

echo "${vars[@]} | $COND"
for ((i=0; i<N;++i)); do
  for ((b=0; b<n; ++b)) do
    var=${vars[b]}
    ((val=i & 1<<(n-1-b) ? 1 : 0))
    printf "%*d " ${#var} $val
    eval "(($var=$val))"
  done
  eval "((r=$cond))"
  echo "| $r";
done
```

Output:

```
A B C DD | A AND (B OR C) AND NOT DD
0 0 0  0 | 0
0 0 0  1 | 0
0 0 1  0 | 0
0 0 1  1 | 0
0 1 0  0 | 0
0 1 0  1 | 0
0 1 1  0 | 0
0 1 1  1 | 0
1 0 0  0 | 0
1 0 0  1 | 0
1 0 1  0 | 1
1 0 1  1 | 0
1 1 0  0 | 1
1 1 0  1 | 0
1 1 1  0 | 1
1 1 1  1 | 0
```

It translates the condition in human readable format to [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) format (`AND` to `&&`, `OR` to `||`, `NOT` to `!` and around `(` and `)` set a space. Needed not to misuse `))` in `eval`.). Then it collects all unique variables. Then calculates the size of the truth-table. Then makes a loop for each rows. Inside that loop it makes a nested loop to calculate the value of each variable and set this value. At the end of the main loop is calculates the value of the expression.

It is not bullet proof. Do not use special variables in variable names (`DD=XX` or `A'B`).

So is your [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) code sets the used variables and then calls the transformed condition (see `cond`) in an `eval` (see last `eval`) it evaluates the condition properly. Then the `$r` variable can be used for your own purpose...

I hope this helps!

Comment: This looks really cool,but it's going to take a bit to digest it. I'll be back.

Comment: @Joe: You need only the `COND=` and `cond=` lines and the `eval "((r=$cond))"`. The others are just for the truth-table printout. Result is set in `$r`.

Comment: That's a nice piece of code! Even though I know what it's doing, I still can't quite see how `((val=i & 1<<(n-1-b) ? 1 : 0))` works. I get the syntax, but not the binary math. Could you break it down for me a bit (no pun intended)?

Comment: @Joe: If you have `n` variables, then you have `2^n` rows in the truth-table. The row number is between 0 and `2^n-1`. Each bit of the row number can be considered as the value of a variable (e.g. `A` - 0th bit, `B` - 1st bit, `C` - 2nd bit). Every variable name and the bit count is connected via the `vars` hash and its value is the `b`th bit of the row count. Actually I reversed the bit count (`DD` is the 0th bit) to produce a more convenient truth-table. Example: row `10` is `1010` binary, so 0th bit (can be masked as 2^0, 1<<0), 1st bit mask is 2^1 (1<<1), 2nd bit 2^2 (1<<2), etc.

Comment: @Joe. The `val ? true_val : false_val` is a C like shortcut. If the the val is true (not equal to 0) then result is `true_val` which is `1` in this case. Otherwise `0`. But this is not really needed for you as it is just to check if the solution works well... This solution work only with a limited number of variables. This limit is 32 or 64, I did not check...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. As I said, nice code!